# How to handle @ at password when connecting to mysql in python with magic function

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I want to use %sql magic function to connect to mysql in python:

The syntax is as below:

`%sql mysql://root:password@1234@127.0.0.1/database1`

As there is **@** in the password,

I tried to replace `@` with `%40`, but it still doesn't work.

The error message is as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't using [quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) help you?

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote_plus
>>> quote_plus("mysql://root:password@1234@127.0.0.1/database1")
'mysql%3A%2F%2Froot%3Apassword%401234%40127.0.0.1%2Fdatabase1'
```

Comment: thank you! I tried as below:`conn_string = quote_plus("mysql://root:password@1234@127.0.0.1/database1")`   `%sql $conn_string`     it still doesn't work. The error message is: `Environment variable $DATABASE_URL not set, and no connect string given.
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])`